# How to disable backslash escaping while saving string into file in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, escaping, backslash

Neither of the following line write "a\b" into file

```
fid = fopen('myfile.txt','w'); fprintf(fid, 'a\b'); fclose(fid);

fid = fopen('myfile.txt','wb'); fprintf(fid, 'a\b'); fclose(fid);
```

Probably, Matlab does backslash escaping during save to file.

How to disable this "feature"?

The string should remain intact, i.e. `fprintf(fid, 'a\\b')` is not a solution, `length('a\b')==3` should be `true`.

Answer (score 5):

You could use conversion characters in `fprintf`, i.e. `%s` in this case

```
fid = fopen('myfile.txt','w'); fprintf(fid, '%s', 'a\b'); fclose(fid);
```

Your condition `length('a\b')==3` isn't violated like this, if I am not mistaken

Answer (score 4):

Another alternative is to use [`fwrite`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fwrite.html):

```
fwrite(fid,'a\b','uchar');
```

If you use `'char'` mode, the string will be encoded differently depending on how the file was opened (e.g. UTF encoding).